# compare value of one column sum to other column of same table

Tags: sql

I have a table with some columns.I would like to take sum one column and compare the value to other single column value. if sum of first column equal of last row of other column then ok other wise show this difference.
Example.

Table abc have column code,val_1 and val_2

```
code     val_1    val_2
A_1         200    100
A_1         150     50
A_1         250     25
A_1          50     650
```

Now if sum of val_1 is equal to last row of Val_2 "650" then ok if not equal then show it.

Comment: _Last_ - according to _what_? Any id or timestamp column?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* tables.  There is no "last row".

If you do have an ordering column, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(val_1) over (partition by code) as sum_val_1,
             row_number() over (partition by code order by <orderingcol> desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and sum_val_1 <> val_2;
```

If the last value in `val_2` is always the maximum, then aggregation suffices:

```
select code
from t
group by code
having sum(val_1) <> max(val_2);
```